# Writing function that returns string but with all five or more letters reversed JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, methods

first time posting. I'm writing a function in js that reverses words with more than 5 characters in a given string. It works, but I think it is adding extra "space" strings that it doesn't need if the string inputted is only one word. I know I have too many variables and there is a way better way to do this. I'm pretty new to this, but anything helps. Thanks!

```
const exString = "Hey fellow warriors"
function spinWords(string){
    let newWord = string.split(' ');
    let fiveWord = "";
    let lessWord = "";
    for(i=0; i<newWord.length;i++){
        if(newWord[i].length >=5){
            fiveWord += newWord[i].split('').reverse() + ' ';
            }
        else{
            lessWord += newWord[i]
            }        
    }
    newFiveWord = fiveWord.replace(/,/g,'');
    return lessWord + ' ' + newFiveWord     
}
console.log(spinWords(exString));
```

Comment: There's really no need to concatenate both types of strings into different variables. You can just concatenate the result into one variable (which solves one bug with this code)

Comment: Tip: use plural variable names for collections/arrays - eg `let newWords = string.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const spinWords = str => str
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => word.length >= 5
    ? [...word].reverse().join('')
    : word)
  .join(' ')
  
console.log(spinWords("Hey fellow warriors"))
```

1. Turn the string into an array of words
2. Modify each word. If 5+ letters: `[..word]` turns the string into an array of letters (`'hi'` > `['h', 'i']`). Then reverse the array, and turn the letters back into one string.
3. Undo step one by turning the array into one string.

Comment: "*I'm pretty new to this*" - how about some explanations?

Comment: @freedomn-m I added it

Answer (score 0):

```
function reversedText() {
    let text = prompt("Enter text");
    const words = text?.split(" ");

    const newText = words.map((word) => {
        if (word.length >= 5) {
            return (word.split("").reverse().join(""));
        }
        return word;
    });

    if (newText.length > 0) {
        return newText.filter(notNull).join(" ");
    } else {
        return 'Your sentence have words which have length less than 5';
    }
}

function notNull(value) {
    return value != null
}

console.log(reversedText());
```